# Should I store firebase id token somewhere?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase authentication and I'm wondering if I should store firebase id token somewhere.

Currently, I call this function every time before I call API.

```js
getToken: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
          user.getIdToken().then(function (idToken) {
            resolve(idToken)
          })
        } else {
          this.$router.push('/login')
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Is there any way to improve this processing?
thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.  If you don't need to use it later, then you don't need to store it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I use the token every time I call API. This is why I would like to store the token somewhere so that I can take it quickly.